Company does not interact regarding stock options
I was granted stock options at my previous company.  I had to jump through hoops to purchase a portion of these because my previous chain of command would not answer my inquiries, and the finance department lost or "did not receive" my check.
These options are in Carta.  After I was finally able to purchase these carta reflected this, but for a year the state of the purchase has been stuck in "pending company issues certificate".
I would like to move this process forward.  Since the company is ignoring my communications, how can I proceed to get this "Certificate" and thus presumably actual ownership of the options, without hiring a lawyer?

I don't see any other general answer, except to threaten to get a lawyer... This is going to be highly specific to whatever is going on at that company.

Please clarify if you own options, shares, or some of each. Presumably the certificate refers to shares, not options. Are you entitled to sell any shares? If so, to whom? Are you entitled and/or obligated to exercise any options? Would you be satisfied after the certificate is issued?
